# python importlib dynamic reload does not work

Tags: python, reload, python-importlib

I am implementing tool that allow plugins by other people.
Inside each module there should be a class with the same name as the module.
All the examples in the web seems only working on known module name.
But in my case, the module name must be a parameter.
Also I would like to allow those plugin developers to debug with my tool so that they can make online changes to their plugins.
I use python importlib.reload for this purpose.
Unfortunately I have not succeeded in making my code work.
My code segment is as follows.

```
from importlib import reload

def pluginReload(pluginName, *initialArgs): 
    pluginModule = sys.modules[pluginName]
    pluginModuleX = reload(pluginModule)
    pluginModule = sys.modules[pluginName]
    claasObj = getattr(pluginModule, pluginName)
    pluginInstance = classObj(*initialArgs)

    return pluginInstance
```

Here is another try.

```
def pluginReload(pluginName): 
    pluginModule = sys.modules[pluginName]
    pluginModule = reload(pluginModule)
```

I have experimented with various combination of the above code, but none makes the reload work to reflect change in module pluginName.
I have tried pluginModule and pluginModuleX.

I even tried the very simple example script as follows:

```
from importlib import import_module, reload 
import reloadTest 
aReload = reloadTest.at()

print ("getTest 1: ", aReload.getTest())
print ("sys.modules 1: ", sys.modules.keys())

xx = input()
print ("xx--> ", xx)

aReloadModule = sys.modules['reloadTest']

sys.modules['reloadTest'] = reload(aReloadModule)
print ("sys.modules 2: ", sys.modules.keys())
print ("getTest 2: ", aReload.getTest()) 

sys.exit(-1)
```

which imports the following module reloadTest.

```
class at: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.x = 1

    def getTest(self): 
        print ("hello world 5")
        return self.x
```

But this simple code also did not work.
Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Farn